# Why does Resharper want me to specify a culture in calls to ToString()?

Tags: resharper

I have many calls to the ToString() method in my code and Resharper always highlights this with the error

```
Specify a culture in string conversion explicitly
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Specify+a+culture+in+string+conversion+explicitly) seems to explain it pretty clearly. Has to do with locales mostly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you get when you divde thirty two by one hundred? You probably think the answer is

```
0.32
```

but in French or German (among others), it would be

```
0,32
```

If you don't specify a `CultureInfo` for `ToString`, the current thread culture will be used, which will (usually) depend on the configuration of the machine your code is running on. If you'd like `ToString` to produce results which *don't* depend on machine configuration, you need to specify a `CultureInfo`.

Comment: it seems to me this would mostly cause problems if you are persisting string representations of things but doing `text.toLower() == otherText.toLower()` it isn't going to matter as the culture isn't going to stop the same things being equal, unless I'm missing something